# Facing issue after deploying particular aspx page in windows2008 server

Tags: asp.net

My Asp.net web application is developed in **dotnet4.0 framework (VS2010)**. I have published all my code using PUBLISH WEBSITE option and deployed on **windows server2008[in IIS]**. My application working fine with out any issues after deplyment.

Now in some page lets say products.aspx i got some requirement and i did my changes. Now as per the new requirement my application is working fine in developement machine.

Now i need to deploy the same page **products.aspx** on to my server. I have published my code using **PUBLISH WEBSITE -->Allow this precompiled site to be updatable** option. After publishing successfully completed i took only **product.aspx** page and its respective **dll** and deployed on **windows server2008[in IIS]** .

Now my problem is
after deployment i am trying to access products.aspx, am getting PAGE NOT FOUND message.

Note: If i deploy all my published code am not facing any issue. But when deploy only particular page then only am facing problem.

please suggest me how to overcome this?

Comment: Are you publishing using Web Deploy or File System? Also why do you choose "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable " option?

Comment: We deploy or File System options are not available in my Visual studio. I just goto build menu and there i select Publish website, it prompts me to select path to publish. Can you suggest me any other ideas for deploying only modified or specific aspx files?

Comment: If there is change in only .aspx file then you don't need to rebuild or publish the website instead you can replace .aspx file directly in the server. But if there is change in code-behind then you need to replace dll also.

Comment: Yes there is a changes in .cs file also